# Spotify API Only Returning Some of Users playlists

Tags: python, python-requests, request, spotify, endpoint

I have some Python code that is meant to return the user's playlists. However, it only returns some of my playlists. The documentation says it should return all playlists in my library (all the ones I've created and the ones I've liked). Also, when I use the 'try it' feature on Spotify's website, it works perfectly fine. I've made sure I have the right scopes, the user ID is correct and even made sure my playlists are public (not that it should matter). Here is my code calling the function:

```
def getUsersPlaylists(self, user_id, offset): 
        headers = {
            "Authorization" : f"Bearer {self.access_token}"
        }
        endpoint = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + user_id + '/playlists?offset=' + str(offset) + '&limit=50'
        return requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers).json()
```

and I've also tried this similar function that just uses the user that logged in with OAuth 2.0 rather than providing the user ID:

```
def getUsersPlaylists(self, offset): 
        headers = {
            "Authorization" : f"Bearer {self.access_token}"
        }
        endpoint = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists?offset=' + str(offset) + '&limit=50'
        return requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers).json()
```

What would be causing this? As I said before, it shows some playlists but not others and I cant see a pattern in which playlists it does and doesn't show. Thanks to anyone who can help :)

Comment: How many lists does the user actually have, and how many does the request return?

Comment: The user has under 50 playlists and I'm requesting 50

Comment: What is the value of `offset` in the function call?

Comment: In this case 0. Because there are only 47 playlists

Comment: How many lists are actually returned?

Comment: 19 and they are only the ones I've created. Non of them are the ones that aren't mine but I've liked

Comment: Show us the code that processes the results of the api call.  Maybe the mistake is there.

Comment: `user_playlists_info = spotify_client.getUsersPlaylists(user_id, 0)` this is all. Once I print 'user_playlists_info', I only get 19 playlists

Comment: Are you looking at the "items" list within the response?

Comment: Yes. I put the json into a json file formatter and looked at the 'items'

Comment: Does the "total" item match the number of lists that were actually returned?

Comment: Yes. It says 'total': 19 and the 'next' is 'None', so there is no other page

Comment: Well, it looks like spotify genuinely thinks that the user only has 19 lists.  I see that the documentation page describes this api call as "Get a list of the playlists owned or followed by a Spotify user".  Earlier you said that you expected it to also return lists that you "liked".  Is "like" the same thing as "follow", in spotify lingo?

Comment: Is 19 the correct number of lists that this user actually _owns_?

Comment: I think they do mean the same thing. Even if they don't, it still only returns some of the playlists I own myself. I also find it extra weird that in the 'try it' function on the Spotify website, it works fine. Is there anything I can do? I tried posting to the Spotify community page, but the site is really glitchy and wont load for me :/

Comment: No. I have more than 19 playlists of my own

Comment: I don't use this api, so I'm afraid I don't really have anything else to suggest.  If it works on the "try it" page, then that suggests your code has an error somewhere, but I can't be any more specific...

Answer (score 1):

I just found my problem. I was using the user-read-private and playlist-read-collaborative scopes, but I also needed the playlist-read-private scope. Using this scope fixed my problem.